# Is there a particular reason that stacks and heaps aren't mentioned more often in C++ resources?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

In books such as "C# in a Nutshell", what is allocated on the stack and heap is introduced quite quickly. However, C++ sources such as "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++", the standard, and cppreference.com never mention stacks or heaps with regards to memory allocation - not even when they talk about storage duration/classes. Why is this? Is it implementation specific what is allocated where or is the use of stacks and heaps the same between all programming languages? If the latter is true, I would understand the lack of coverage of where different entities are allocated.

Comment: The difference between C# and C++ is that C# targets a very small set of platforms, where both stacks and heaps really exist. On the contrary, C++ is much more generic and its creators did not want to restrict its portability to such platforms only.

Comment: Because there exist implementations without stacks and heaps. Not having a heap is normal for your average C and C++ embedded system. There's even some very low end 8 bitters that don't have a stack, yet got C compiler support.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stacks and heaps are not C++ *language* concepts (save the odd function in the C++ standard library), but are *implementation* concepts.

That's why C++ books will use the standard terms *automatic* and *dynamic* storage instead.

If you were reading a book on compiler design and implementation then you'd fully expect comprehensive prose on stacks and heaps.

Comment: So a "yes" to "Is it implementation specific what is allocated where"?

Comment: @Dip: So long as the allocation is along the lines of the standard, yes.

Comment: But then why is it just about always covered in all C# sources - such as "Reference types are allocated on the heap"?

Comment: @Dip: Because a "heap" is an explicit C# language concept.

Comment: For instance C# in a nutshell and another language book that I cannot remember the name of covers this and are not really books about compilation.

Comment: Where did you learn this? I mean have read several books and not encountered this information. I think it is quite important to know..

Comment: I see. But such C++ sources as I mentioned in my question have a very extensive use of "implementation specific", so I just wonder why they didn't use it in something like the memory model of C++ - wouldn't that make sense? Such as "the actual allocation is implementation specific."

Comment: @Dip: C++ intentionally doesn't say much about its memory model. In this way it can be used on very many difference machines. Although in this respect C is even more flexible.

Comment: Alright. Btw., I am just asking questions for clarification now; you have answered the actual question in way that I understand. Anyway, so what you are saying is that the lack of elaboration of C++'s memory model could/should be interpreted as meaning that parts of the model (e.g allocation) is implementation specific?

Comment: @Dip: You got it!

Comment: @Dip C# is a language developed by a single vendor, and literally tailored to a specific execution environment i.e. .NET. Comparing its specification to that of a language as broad in scope (as others have mentioned) as C++, is necessarily difficult. I know automobile comparisons are overused, but this is like avoiding the term "gas tank" when speaking very broadly of autos because some of them may not have one, but instead e.g. use batteries or even flywheels.

Comment: Even in C#, [stacks and heaps are an implementation detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/). It's a shame that the official documentation mentions them

Comment: It is *entirely unimportant* that some memory is allocated by incrementing a pointer called the "stack pointer" and other memory is allocated by incrementing a different pointer called the "generation 0 heap pointer", because C# doesn't let you observe any difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in is not a book about the C++ Programming Language/Standard, but about the implementation of e.g the C++ Standard Library. There you would read more about Memory allocation on Stack/Heap. For example "The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference" from Nicolai M. Josuttis.

Because C/C++ can also be used on platforms without any dynamic memory allocation support(for some embedded applications the compiler even prohibits usage of new and malloc), there is not much reference inside C++ programming books.